# Unknown Coder URN beam:coder:pickled_python:v1 when executing beam with python jdbcIO

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-sql

I have an Apache Beam pipeline which tries to write to Postgres after reading from BigQuery. The code uses JdbcIO connector and Dataflow runner.

The code is as follow :

```
output = (
    pipeline
    | 'ReadTable' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query='', use_standard_sql=True)
    | 'Write to jdbc' >> WriteToJdbc(
              driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
              jdbc_url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?currentSchema=public',
              username='',
              password='',
              table_name='extract'
    )
)
```

I am getting an error about URN coder:

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Coder URN beam:coder:pickled_python:v1. Known URNs: [beam:coder:avro:generic:v1, beam:coder:bytes:v1, beam:coder:bool:v1, beam:coder:string_utf8:v1, beam:coder:kv:v1, beam:coder:varint:v1, beam:coder:interval_window:v1, beam:coder:iterable:v1, beam:coder:timer:v1, beam:coder:length_prefix:v1, beam:coder:global_window:v1, beam:coder:windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:param_windowed_value:v1, beam:coder:double:v1, beam:coder:row:v1, beam:coder:sharded_key:v1]
```

I could not find what is the problem with that ?